# asp.net error: Parser Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm suddenly getting below message in browser when debugging application out of Visual Studio 2008 target .net fw 3.5

Research online lead me to confirm the following:
The "Inherits" in markup page matches code-behind namespace class reference: "USFBugTracker.UpdateContracts".  I also checked that the target CPU (x86) is correct.

I'll gladly post some code but when debugging not even getting to the point of running anything. I'm getting this debugging.  I've not yet published this anywhere.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'USFBugTracker.UpdateContracts'.

Source Error:

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UpdateContracts.aspx.cs"
Line 2:      Inherits="USFBugTracker.UpdateContracts" %>
Line 3:
```

Comment: Check your code-behind for syntax errors.

Comment: Has the type been built into the currently loaded assembly?  Try a clean build.

Comment: Sorry I should've mentioned the application is built.

Answer (score 0):

Check inside yhe bin folder of your application if, for some reason, the contained dll does not have defined the USFBugTracker.UpdateContracts object.

Comment: In bin folder I do see USFBugTracker.dll

Comment: so try to cleanup the asp.net temporary files

Comment: Not sure what cleanup means but I just tried deleting both "obj" and "bin" folders and rebuilding.  It rebuilt fine but I get same error on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your name space in the codebehind file does match with what the Inherits Tag is referencing in your html.

Comment: Yes. They match as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

If by

> debugging out of Visual Studio

you mean just running it in IIS - it sounds like you haven't configured the directory to be an Application, hence it is looking in the bin folder of the parent application and hence not finding the correct DLLs.

Comment: In bin folder I do see USFBugTracker.dll

Comment: @maatthias - I don't think you understood my answer.  If the folder isn't set as an Application in IIS, it won't look in that bin folder!

Comment: I know next to nothing about IIS.  How do I set the folder as an application?